# Calculation of Response time in C# Windows application

Tags: c#

I am developing windows  application. I want to calculate response time for every web page navigated in my application.

For every navigation it has gone through following events in sequence:
1) WebBrowser_BeforeNavigate2
2) WebBrowser_NavigateComplete2 and 
3) WebBrowser_DocumentCompleted

So I am starting stopwatch at event "WebBrowser_BeforeNavigate2" and stopping stopwatch at "WebBrowser_NavigateComplete2". and considering elapsed time as "Response time". Is this the correct way to calculate response time?

Comment: Seems reasonable, but for questions if your code is correct you should go to code review/software engeneering (CR: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ SE: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @when referring other sites, it is often helpful to point that [cross-posting is frowned upon](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info)